# Format DateTime in php

Tags: php

I need to format Date time to specific date format using php.

Now date format
2014-02-10 09:32:24

I need format
2014/02/10

> error is :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ModifiedDate' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in ................. line

Here i tried like this

```
    <?php
 include(config.php);

 $sql = "SELECT Id,Title,description,Image,Category,ModifiedDate from News WHERE   ISActive=true";

 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){


 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
                    $Mod = $test['ModifiedDate'];
        $ModifiedDate = date_format($Mod, 'yyyy/MM/dd');


        echo"<td><font color='black'>"$ModifiedDate"</font></td>";

   }

  }

  else
  {
echo "No Records";
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to concatenate the variable. Do like this

```
echo"<td><font color='black'>".$ModifiedDate."</font></td>";
                            //^-----        ^-----  Add those dots !
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 $ModifiedDate = date_format($Mod, 'Y/m/d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below format,

```
 date_format($Mod, 'YY/MM/DD');
```